# Deleting column values within a matrix

Tags: r

I have been at it for a while with this one. I hope one of you can help me.  I have a large matrix: 122 rows and 6005 columns. One column [,1] lists items codes. Within this column are 25 practice trials I want to get rid of.  I tried using this code:

```
  x1=nw[,1][-c(1:25), 1:6005]
```

But it produces an incorrect dimension error. If I isolate this column I get the results that I want. Why will this not generalize to the whole matrix? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Deos this solve your problem,

```
m <- matrix(1:732610, 122 , 6005)
z <- m[-c(1:25),-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just remove values from a matrix, because it has a set dimension (number of rows x number of columns). Instead, try replacing the values with missing values (NA's).

```
nw <- matrix(rnorm(122*6005, 5, 1), nrow = 122, ncol = 6005)
nw[,1][1:25] <- NA
nw[,1:4]
```

Then you can treat NA's with na.omit/na.rm functions. For example

```
mean(nw[,1], na.rm = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my post. After I posted this, I went back to my code and came up with something similar.